# Xposed hooking every TextView in my device

Tags: java, android, reflection, root, xposed

I'm hooking the android framework itself,not a specific app,this is my code:

```
 public void handleLoadPackage(XC_LoadPackage.LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
        
        if (lpparam == null||lpparam.packageName == null || lpparam.processName == null)
            return;

        if (lpparam.packageName.equals("android")) {
            XposedBridge.log("Hooked into Android framework.");


            if (!sInitialized) {
                sInitialized = true;
                hookSetVisibility(lpparam);
            }
        }
    }


    private void hookSetVisibility(XC_LoadPackage.LoadPackageParam lpparam) {

        final Class<?> mViewGroup = XposedHelpers.findClass("android.widget.TextView", lpparam.classLoader);
        for (final Method method : mViewGroup.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            if (true == Modifier.isAbstract(method.getModifiers())) {
                XposedBridge.log("skip abstract:" + method.getName());
                continue;
            }
            XposedBridge.log("----" + method.getName());
            XposedBridge.hookMethod(method, methodHook);
        }
    }

    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    XC_MethodHook methodHook = new XC_MethodHook() {
        @Override
        protected void beforeHookedMethod(XC_MethodHook.MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {

            XposedBridge.log("before hook log");
        }

        @Override
        protected void afterHookedMethod(XC_MethodHook.MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
            //param.setResult(false);
            XposedBridge.log("after hook log");       
        }
    };
```

The module indeed prints nicely the all class method names as can seen in the [android framework](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-mr0-release/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java),but the `BeforeHookedMethod` and the `afterHookMethod` never get called......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you are trying to limiting the hook the "Android framework" only which will fail as the Android framework is not a separate process but included in every app process, respectively the `TextView` elements are part of the app process they are shown in.

As far as I remember `handleLoadPackage` is called once per app process which allows you to decide if or if not you want to hook something in this specific app process.

But as you want to hook a certain UI element in any app, you should not apply a filter here. So in the end you should remove the filter (or only filter out apps that make problems with your hook) and then directly call `hookSetVisibility`.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.
so if I undersand correctly,you cannot hook the framework class itself,eventhough every view (for example) class created,used the framework view super class,but only hook specific android packages...right?

Comment: @itapi In the end you can only hook the app processes and by the packageName you can decide in your code if you want to execute your XPosed hook in the current app or not. As Xposed injects itself into the central Dalvik process which is the "mother-process", all app-processes are forked from, Xposed by default is active in all app processes (and thus your hook would be active, too).